# nodejs `arguments` is object but in the browser, it is an `array`

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, browser

When I access `arguments` from inside called function in nodejs...

```
echo '!function(){ console.log(arguments) }(1,2,3)' | node
```

... it outputs an object ...

```
{ '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3 }
```

... but in google chrome ...

```
!function(){ console.log(arguments) }(1,2,3)
```

... outputs ...

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Why is it not consistent? What other js environments have this different behaviour? Is it ok for me to use `arguments`? How can I ensure it is always an array before I use it?

Comment: Arrays *are* objects. You're just seeing variation in the way that the `console` objects work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no rules for console output. The output doesn't represent anything that has to do with the language standard.

If you create a program that logs values from within a JS program, you're free to display those values however you want.

The `arguments` object is the same in both places. Only how it's being displayed is different.

> How can I ensure it is always an array before I use it?

It's never an array. It's always an array-like object. In both cases its showing a value at object members `0`, `1` and `2`. Just uses different display syntax to do it.

In Chrome, try creating an object like this:

```
var my_obj = {
    "0": 1,
    "2": 3,
    "1": 2,
    length: 3,
    splice: function(){},
};
```

And the log it in the console. It'll probably look like an Array literal, though it's obviously not.

Comment: that is interesting. Additionally, I solved my problem with: `var args_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`

Answer (score 0):

**It's not an Array in the browser, either**. The `arguments` object has actually been in JavaScript longer than Arrays have, and when Arrays were first added to JavaScript (back in its 1.1 days), they didn't update `arguments` to be an Array. They haven't done it since then either, because of worries about backward-compatibility. **It shows up in some browser consoles as though it were an Array because the debug console knows that most people plan to treat it as one anyway**.

**But the `arguments` object is close enough to an Array that it's easy to convert**. One way to do it is like this:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

`Array.prototype.slice`, like most of `Array.prototype`'s methods, is written to be generic: **you can call it on Objects that aren't Arrays, and as long as they have properties with numeric names and a `length` property that's a Number, it'll work**. The `arguments` object has both of these things, so these functions will work on it.

The `slice` function returns an Array which is a shallow copy of whatever object was passed into it, starting and ending at whatever numbers you specify. **We tell it to start at zero, and because we didn't say where to stop, it assumes we want it to stop at the end**, wherever that might be. This way, we copy all of the elements of `arguments` into a new Array, and now you can do whatever other Array things you want with it.